# How can I set a fixed height for my entire webpage?

Tags: html, css

I thought this was a simple fix:

```
body
{
    height: 1054px;
}

html
{
    height: 1054px;
}
```

Wouldn't this set the max height of the page to `1054px`? I have also tried these workarounds but they didn't work with what I wanted:

```
html
{
   overflow: hidden;
}

<body><table id = "myTable"><tr><td> ..... </tr></td></body>

#myTable
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

How do I set an absolute height for a webpage? Also I am more interested in why the `body` and `html` `height` calls wouldn't work. I do a lot of `position: relative` calls, would that have an effect on it?

Comment: You may change `html{overflow:hidden;}` to `body{overflow:hidden;}` in second CSS

Comment: I might be wrong but, I dont think you need to set the height in body as it is inherited from html

Comment: I get worried about `overflow: hidden` on those elements though. If i do it on `html` and say someone minimized the page or something, then half of the page becomes unviewable. Is this the case with `body`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`width` and `height` do set absolute widths and heights of an element respectively. `max-width`, `max-height`, `min-width` and `min-height` are seperate properties.

Example of a page with 1054px square content and a full background:

```
html {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://www.example.com/somelargeimage.jpg);
  background-position: top center;
  background-color: #000;
}

body {
  width: 1054px;
  height: 1054px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

However, since you seem to be table styling (urgh), it would probably be far more sensible to set the height of the table to 1054px and let the body adjust itself automatically to encompass the entire table. (Keep the html style proposed above, of course.)

Comment: Ill give this a try. The table styling won't be an issue. I just read somewhere that tables can be used to set max page height and width, thats why I used them

Answer (score 2):

Good question. I’m not sure, but have you tried using a single `<div>` (or `<section>`) inside `<body>`, and setting the `width`, `height` and `overflow: hidden` on that? Browsers might give special treatment to `<html>` and `<body>`.

Comment: I tried that on another page I had and it worked out pretty well. It also worked in Facebook (which is what most of my development is in) so thats a plus as well

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the CSS margin of body to 0?  Otherwise there will be some amt (depending on browser) of margin that is included in your page height (and width) but isn't controlled by the height style;

In CSS:

```
body: { margin: 0; }
```

IN jQuery:

```
$('body').css('margin', 0);
```