# how to set default height/width of aspx web page?

Tags: asp.net

I want to set the size of webpage.

I did this but not working

```
<body style="height:30%;width:30%;">
```

any help

Comment: If you want to add `height` and `width` to `body` tag you need to make it explicitly like `body{height:auto; width: 960px; margin:0 auto;}` % won't work on `body` tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set a fixed height for my entire webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965007/how-can-i-set-a-fixed-height-for-my-entire-webpage)

Answer (score 1):

try java script code. basically, when it loads, it will run javascript that will open another window with the correct dimenson and without all the unnecessary toolbars and close the original opener window.

so on your bootstrap page, you do something like:

`window.onload = function() {
        var w = window.open("about:blank", "main", "width=640,height=480", true)
         window.opener = "main";
         window.open("", "_parent", "");
         w.opener.close();
    }`

may be this can help

Answer (score 0):

The size of a web page is the size of the browser window. Basically what you want to control is the size of the content inside that page.

A basic approach would be to create a table element right after body and set a size for that table, then wrap all your content inside that table.

Example:

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr><td width="30%">
       All content goes here
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Note that when setting dimensions with a percentage, the dimensions will be proportional to the size of the browser window. E.g. the page will look different depending on whether the browser window is maximized or not.